# Which API can we use for integration of MS Office 365 API with different application? MS office365 or MS graph?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

We are working on integration of  MS Office 365 API with different application.

I had a query regarding the MS Office 365 and MS Graph API

Which API's we should use for our integration project? and What is the customer base for MS Office 365 and MS Graph API?

Comment: any pointers will be helpful..

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your detail requirement.

*With Microsoft Graph to access data from services like Outlook, OneDrive, Azure Active Directory, OneNote, Planner, and Office Graph, with a single access token through a single endpoint.*

*However, some features may be available on the individual service endpoints, but not yet on Microsoft Graph.*

If all your features required is supported by Microsoft Graph, the Microsoft Graph is recommend. More detail about how to choose the endpoint, you can refer to [here](http://dev.office.com/chooseapiendpoint)

Comment: Will the future enhancements be performed in office365 or MS graph Api?

Comment: Yes. You can see those preview feature in the beta version API. And get the stable version updates from [release notes](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/release_notes)

Comment: @FeiXue - We plan to integrate office 365 apps like teams, planner etc in our web application too. Is there a better approach than using microsoft graph api to do this? We want to use all the operations that these apps support in our application. Creating UI's and making graph api calls underneath would reduce the time to market. A simple and seamless integration is what I am looking for. Thoughts?